# Remove file extension and path from a string in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, file-extension, filepath

I want to obtain a file name without its path (if it is part of the string) and also the extension.

For example:

```
/path/to/file/fileName.txt     # results in "fileName"
fileName.txt                   # results in "fileName"
/path/to/file/file.with.periods.txt    # results in "file.with.periods"
```

So basically, I want to remove anything before and including the last "/" if present and also the last "." along with any meta characters after it.

Sorry for such a novice question, but I am new to perl.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For portably getting the basename of a file given a full path, I'd recommend the [`File::Basename`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) module, which is part of the core.

To do heuristics on file extensions I'd go for a regular expression like

```
(my $without_extension = $basename) =~ s/\.[^.]+$//;
```

Comment: Regarding basename I just read: "This function is provided for compatibility with the Unix shell command basename(1) . It does NOT always return the file name portion of a path as you might expect. To be safe, if you want the file name portion of a path use fileparse()".

Comment: Yes, there's more than one function in the `File::Basename` module, and they all do different things. Pick the one that does what you want. Additionally, similar functionality exists in `File::Spec` as `splitpath`

Answer (score 24):

Although others have responded, after reading a bit on basename per rafl's answer:

```
($file,$dir,$ext) = fileparse($fullname, qr/\.[^.]*/);
# dir="/usr/local/src/" file="perl-5.6.1.tar" ext=".gz"
```

Seems to solve the problem in one line.

Are there any problems related with this, opposed to the other solutions?

Answer (score 19):

Assuming that the path separator is `'/'`, you can do it with a pair of [substitutions](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html):

```
$name =~ s{^.*/}{};     # remove the leading path  
$name =~ s{\.[^.]+$}{}; # remove the extension
```

You can also write that as a single substitution:

```
$name =~ s{^.*/|\.[^.]+$}{}g;
```

Comment: @Phalgun `[^.]` is a *negated character class*, i.e. it will match any character that is not a dot (`.`). (Note that `.` lose its special meaning when used inside a character class.) `[^.]+` will match *one or more* such characters. See [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for more details.